# High data usage on a raspberry IOT

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have notice a signification data usage on my pi even when I am not using it. this can be a problem as I am using a IOT sim card with a small cap.

I have setup iftop and monitored the traffic for a couple hours. here are few of the connections my pi had that I have no idea why. during that time my was not supposed to anything.

- ntp15.doctor.com
- vf1.bbnx.net
- y.ns.gin.ntt.net
- 129.250.35.251
- 10.177.0.210
- cloudflare.com

Would anyone be able to shed some light on those connections and confirm if those might be reason for the high data usage.

Comment: 1) Define high, 2) what are the actual bytes transferred for each of those addresses, 3) What changes have you made standard Raspbian install, 4) Does the SIM have a publicly routable IP address? 5) 10.x.x.x is a private address that will be to do with your provider.